# dynamically built form with jquery modal dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a form that is built when someone clicks the `Edit` button.  Try this out here in the  [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UtNaa/42/).

Instead of hiding the table and showing the ugly form, I wanted to put this into a jquery modal dialog with the form inside of it.

I tried adding this outside the edit function but it doesn't seem to work:

```
var dialogOpts={
    modal:true,
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable:false,
    width: 625
}
var $dialogform = $('#editform').dialog(dialogOpts); //init dialog    

$('#editbutton').click(function(e) {
    $dialogform.dialog('open');
});
```

Any ideas? Note: if you play around with the fiddle you will have to remove the `mydiv.show()/hide()` calls along with the if/else that is used to display the form instead of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/UtNaa/58/)

Not much else to really say. I would explain, but a) I have to run and b) the code does it for me.